# Symfony2 + Doctrine2 entities not mapped (result is null)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entity TBag and TCustomer, the TBag entity contain a reference to TCustomer but when I try to get my TBag entity the associated entities is null.

The entities have been generated from the database with the doctrine command line `doctrine:generate:entities`

Thanks for your time :-)

TBag data :

```
id;extn_id;bagNumber;customer_id;store_id;delivery_date;order_remarks;currency;t_bag_status_id
1;;1;3;1;2015-08-25;test;1;0
```

TCustomer data :

```
id;name;firstName;email;phoneNumber;address;postalCode;city;country_id;birthDate;ipAddress;localization   
3;Quentin;Test;quentin.test@outlook.com;0655555555;30 rue 123;86360;Poitiers;0;1994-11-06;192.168.1.24;FR
```

The TBagController code :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('LedcMainBundle:TBag')->find(1);
```

TBag entity :

```
namespace Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TBag
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="t_bag", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="orderNumber_UNIQUE", columns={"bagNumber"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_t_order_t_customer1_idx", columns={"customer_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_t_order_t_store1_idx", columns={"store_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_t_bag_t_bag_status1_idx", columns={"t_bag_status_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\Repository\TBagRepository")
 */
class TBag
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="extn_id", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $extnId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bagNumber", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $bagnumber;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="delivery_date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deliveryDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="order_remarks", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $orderRemarks;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="currency", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * @var \TBagStatus
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TBagStatus")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="t_bag_status_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $tBagStatus;

    /**
     * @var \TCustomer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TCustomer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $customer;

    /**
     * @var \TStore
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TStore")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="store_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $store;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set extnId
     *
     * @param string $extnId
     *
     * @return TBag
     */
    public function setExtnId($extnId)
    {
        $this->extnId = $extnId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get extnId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExtnId()
    {
        return $this->extnId;
    }

    /**
     * Set bagnumber
     *
     * @param string $bagnumber
     *
     * @return TBag
     */
    public function setBagnumber($bagnumber)
    {
        $this->bagnumber = $bagnumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bagnumber
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBagnumber()
    {
        return $this->bagnumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set deliveryDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $deliveryDate
     *
     * @return TBag
     */
    public function setDeliveryDate($deliveryDate)
    {
        $this->deliveryDate = $deliveryDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deliveryDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDeliveryDate()
    {
        return $this->deliveryDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set orderRemarks
     *
     * @param string $orderRemarks
     *
     * @return TBag
     */
    public function setOrderRemarks($orderRemarks)
    {
        $this->orderRemarks = $orderRemarks;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get orderRemarks
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOrderRemarks()
    {
        return $this->orderRemarks;
    }

    /**
     * Set currency
     *
     * @param integer $currency
     *
     * @return TBag
     */
    public function setCurrency($currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get currency
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    /**
     * Set tBagStatus
     *
     * @param \Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TBagStatus $tBagStatus
     *
     * @return TBag
     */
    public function setTBagStatus(\Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TBagStatus $tBagStatus = null)
    {
        $this->tBagStatus = $tBagStatus;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tBagStatus
     *
     * @return \Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TBagStatus
     */
    public function getTBagStatus()
    {
        return $this->tBagStatus;
    }

    /**
     * Set customer
     *
     * @param \Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TCustomer $customer
     *
     * @return TBag
     */
    public function setCustomer(\Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TCustomer $customer = null)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer
     *
     * @return \Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TCustomer
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    /**
     * Set store
     *
     * @param \Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TStore $store
     *
     * @return TBag
     */
    public function setStore(\Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TStore $store = null)
    {
        $this->store = $store;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get store
     *
     * @return \Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TStore
     */
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->store;
    }
}
```

TCustomer entity :

```
<?php

namespace Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TCustomer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="t_customer", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="email_UNIQUE", columns={"email"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_t_customer_country1_idx", columns={"country_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\Repository\TCustomerRepository")
 */
class TCustomer
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstName", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phoneNumber", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phonenumber;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="text", length=65535, nullable=true)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="postalCode", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $postalcode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="birthDate", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $birthdate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ipAddress", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $ipaddress;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="localization", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $localization;

    /**
     * @var \TCountry
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TCountry")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $country;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return TCustomer
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstname
     *
     * @param string $firstname
     *
     * @return TCustomer
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return TCustomer
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set phonenumber
     *
     * @param string $phonenumber
     *
     * @return TCustomer
     */
    public function setPhonenumber($phonenumber)
    {
        $this->phonenumber = $phonenumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phonenumber
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPhonenumber()
    {
        return $this->phonenumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param string $address
     *
     * @return TCustomer
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Set postalcode
     *
     * @param string $postalcode
     *
     * @return TCustomer
     */
    public function setPostalcode($postalcode)
    {
        $this->postalcode = $postalcode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get postalcode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPostalcode()
    {
        return $this->postalcode;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     *
     * @return TCustomer
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set birthdate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $birthdate
     *
     * @return TCustomer
     */
    public function setBirthdate($birthdate)
    {
        $this->birthdate = $birthdate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get birthdate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getBirthdate()
    {
        return $this->birthdate;
    }

    /**
     * Set ipaddress
     *
     * @param string $ipaddress
     *
     * @return TCustomer
     */
    public function setIpaddress($ipaddress)
    {
        $this->ipaddress = $ipaddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ipaddress
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIpaddress()
    {
        return $this->ipaddress;
    }

    /**
     * Set localization
     *
     * @param string $localization
     *
     * @return TCustomer
     */
    public function setLocalization($localization)
    {
        $this->localization = $localization;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get localization
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocalization()
    {
        return $this->localization;
    }

    /**
     * Set country
     *
     * @param \Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TCountry $country
     *
     * @return TCustomer
     */
    public function setCountry(\Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TCountry $country = null)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return \Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TCountry
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }
}
```

\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($entity) :

```
object(stdClass)#531 (10) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(34) "Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TBag"
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["extnId"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["bagnumber"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["deliveryDate"]=>
  object(stdClass)#557 (3) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["date"]=>
    string(25) "2015-08-25T00:00:00+02:00"
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  ["orderRemarks"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["currency"]=>
  int(1)
  ["tBagStatus"]=>
  object(stdClass)#558 (6) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(40) "Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TBagStatus"
    ["__IS_PROXY__"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["__PROXY_INITIALIZED__"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["lib"]=>
    NULL
    ["description"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["customer"]=>
  object(stdClass)#562 (15) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(39) "Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TCustomer"
    ["__IS_PROXY__"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["__PROXY_INITIALIZED__"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
    ["firstname"]=>
    NULL
    ["email"]=>
    NULL
    ["phonenumber"]=>
    NULL
    ["address"]=>
    NULL
    ["postalcode"]=>
    NULL
    ["city"]=>
    NULL
    ["birthdate"]=>
    NULL
    ["ipaddress"]=>
    NULL
    ["localization"]=>
    NULL
    ["country"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["store"]=>
  object(stdClass)#591 (12) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(36) "Ledc\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\TStore"
    ["__IS_PROXY__"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["__PROXY_INITIALIZED__"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
    ["contact"]=>
    NULL
    ["email"]=>
    NULL
    ["phonenumber"]=>
    NULL
    ["address"]=>
    NULL
    ["postalcode"]=>
    NULL
    ["city"]=>
    NULL
    ["localization"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you create one directional relation you need create bidirectional

From manual:

> A one-to-many association has to be bidirectional, unless you are using an additional join-table. This is necessary, because of the foreign key in a one-to-many association being defined on the “many” side. Doctrine needs a many-to-one association that defines the mapping of this foreign key.
>
> This bidirectional mapping requires the mappedBy attribute on the OneToMany association and the inversedBy attribute on the ManyToOne association.

On link below you  will find example of how to do it:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional